# why thr error invocation of init method failed occurs while running in eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, hibernate, maven

I am trying to run spring mvc code using Maven and hibernate. Below I am providing different files I am using. The error I am getting in the console is:-

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0':
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)

Snapshot from Eclipse window:-

[image]

These are dependencies:-
[image]

**web xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>ApplicationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB_INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>


  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet> 
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispactherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.springmvc</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringMVC</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringMVC Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
  <java-version>1.8 </java-version>
  <org.springframework-version>4.2.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.36</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SpringMVC</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns ="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx ="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc ="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation ="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd"

>

<!-- Enable autowire -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- If you use MySQL Database comment out this bean and let others commented  -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" ></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/tests" ></property>
        <property name="username" value="root" ></property>
        <property name="password" value="zahid1212" ></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- SQL Server 2012 and 2014 Database drivers and connectivity code -->
    <!-- <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" ></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=mydb" ></property>
        <property name="username" value="sa" ></property>
        <property name="password" value="abcd@1234" ></property>
    </bean> -->

    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" ></property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.entities" ></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <!-- SQL Dialect -->
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>

                <!-- SQL Server 2014 Dialect -->
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop> -->

                <!-- Your required Database Name -->
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">tests</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
                <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" ></tx:annotation-driven>

     <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" ></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**servlet xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" ></property>
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" ></property>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

What might have causing this?

Comment: You are missing org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration, is Hibernate on your classpath?

Comment: I added now, it solved!